# Understanding mesh for a cylinder

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, ansys

I came across this video on YouTube, and would like to know more about the mesh, such as the internal structure.

Is there a reason to do it that way?

Am i correct in saying there is an o-grid around the cylinder?

[image: enter image description]

Source:https://www.bing.com/videos/riverview/relatedvideo?&q=circular+cylinder+CFD+ansys+icem&&mid=835B3DE4545163852C9F835B3DE4545163852C9F&&FORM=VRDGAR